# .6 WebApi conflict in Win8/Metro App

Tags: wcf-web-api

I am trying to use the .6 WebApi in a C# metro app.
I am able to add the .6 dll references to a win8 console app, but I can't get it to work in a Metro/Xaml app.  I can add Microsoft.Net.Http.Formatting, but when I add System.net.http, it conficts with the Systemm.net.http dll in the GAC I think.

```
var resp = httpClient.GetAsync("").Result;
Person person = resp.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>().Result;
```

Has anyone been able to do this simple two lines of code in a Win8/Metro/Xaml app?

As I mentioned before this works in a console app if you change the target framework from .net Framework 4.5 Client Profile to .Net Framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

The System.Net.Http classes in WCF Web API are a 4.0 version of the new System.Net.Http classes in 4.5. When developing for Win8, use the .NET 4.5 assemblies instead.

Comment: Pedro thanks for your reply. I am aware I need to use the 4.5 version, but VS will not let you add that dll as a reference.  When you add it, nothing happens. I imagine because it says the dll is already in the gac.  I am just guessing.  Please try to add it to your project and paste those two lines in your poject and note the error.  Thanks.

Comment: Are you using VS11? Unfortunately, I don't have VS11 yet, so I cannot reproduce that problem.